# Facebook send button integration error for website

Tags: facebook, authentication, send

I'm trying to integrate a Facebook send button into my site using Facebook app. I have created an app in Facebook, and provided my site url in the website link:

I'm using the the following code in my webpage:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '1xxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

<script>
  function trace(message) {
      var div = document.getElementById('trace');
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + message + '<br/>';
  }
</script>
```

It’s not displaying a window to login for sending mail to friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the markup for the send plugin.  It will look something like this:

`<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>`

Also the `js.src =` line should be like:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={APPID}";`

Answer (score 0):

I added the javascriptSDK and then   Send button code from facebook. The total code follows like this  :    In my Head :

> `<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>       FB.init({
>         appId      : '1xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
>         channelUrl : 'http://example.com/', // Channel File
>         status     : true, // check login status
>         cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
>         xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
>       }); };
>   // Load the SDK Asynchronously (function(d){ var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
>        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
>        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
>      }(document));
>   </script><script>(function(d, s, id) {`
>   //IN the Body Section

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div> <br/> <div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com/"></div>
```